# Geodjango - in memory r-tree index

Tags: python, django, geodjango, r-tree

How can I create an r-tree index in memory, using Geodjango?

I have a number of fixed polygons (hardcoded) and I would like to check in which of these polygons does a point belong.

I would like to do this in memory to avoid being dependent on a spatial database.

Comment: Hey @HelgiBorg, I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is a library named: [`Rtree`](https://pypi.org/project/Rtree/) which is independent of a spatially enabled database.

From the [tutorial:](http://toblerity.org/rtree/tutorial.html)

```
# Import the library and create an index:
from rtree import index
idx = index.Index()

# Insert your fixed polygons to the index by the envelope (bounding box)
# coordinates of those polygons:
for index, polygon in enumerate(my_polygon_list):
    idx.insert(index, polygon.envelope)

# To query with a point you can do the following (explanation after the example):
potential_polys = list(idx.intersection((point.x, point.y, point.x, point.y)))
```

**Break it up:**

- The part of the tutorial on how to set up a Rtree index is pretty simple.
- A Geometry's bounding box (or envelope) coordinates must have the following format:
   
  `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)` or `(left, bottom, right, top)`.
- On the documentation is stated that:

  > Inserting a point, i.e. where `left == right` && `top == bottom`, will essentially insert a single point entry into the index instead of copying extra coordinates and inserting them. There is no shortcut to explicitly insert a single point, however.

  So we are using this "quirk" to apply our point to polygon `intersection` query on the index.